# Programmatically assigning an existing ssl cert to a website in iis6 via powershell or vbscript

Tags: iis-6, powershell, vbscript

I have the following powershell script that creates a new website in IIS6:

https://github.com/dagda1/iis6/blob/master/create-site.ps1

Does anyone know how I can assign an existing ssl cert to the website?

I know I can set the port number using adsutil.vbs like this:

cscript adsutil.vbs set w3svc/xxx/securebindings ":443:somewhere.com"

But I am drawing a big blank when it comes to assigning an existing ssl certificate.

Thanks

Paul

Answer (score 0):

See this answer from StackOverflow:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4585809/programmatically-assigning-an-existing-ssl-cert-to-a-website-in-iis6-via-powershe/4590185#4590185